# How to install plug-in for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation

I want to be able to use a application written in Java that uses injection, therefore I need one of the plug-ins mentioned [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Dependency_Injection). One of the pages where org.eclipse.e4.core.di.jar is available, is [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgeclipsee4coredijar.htm) one.

What do I have to do now? The answers to the other questions on Stack Overflow do not help. I use Juno if that matters.

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/Install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do Help>Install New Software and then add this as the address

`http://download.eclipse.org/e4/downloads/drops/R-0.14-201306242200/repository/`

Comment: When I was trying to install only Eclipse e4 Tools (Incubation) version 0.14.0.v20130620-0935, I got this message: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse e4 Tools (Incubation) 0.14.0.v20130620-0935 (org.eclipse.e4.core.tools.feature.feature.group 0.14.0.v20130620-0935)

Comment: Follow the steps in the link I posted in the comments, you need to install the Eclipse sdk first